# SQLite Database: One Big vs. Several Small? Write to Database in Parallel?

Tags: python, sqlite

As I'm new to sqlite databases, I highly appreciate every useful comment, answer or reference to interesting threads and websites. Here's my situation:

I have a directory with 400 txt files each with the size of ~7GB. The relevant information in these files are written into a sqlite database resulting in a 17.000.000x4 table, which takes approximately 1 day. Later on the database will be queried only by me to further analyze the data.

The whole process of creating the database could be significantly accelerated, if it is possible to write to a database in parallel. For instance, I could run several processes in parallel, each process taking only one of the 400 txt files as input and writing the results to the database. So is it possible to let several processes write to a database in parallel?

---

**EDIT1:** Answer w.r.t. W4t3randWinds comment: It is possible (and faster) to process 1 file per core, write the results into a database and merge all databases after that. However, write into 1 database using multi threading is not possible.

---

Furthermore, I was wondering whether it would be more efficient to create several databases instead of one big database? For instance, does it make sense to create a database per txt file resulting in 400 databases consisting of a 17.000.000/400 x 4 table?

At last, I'm storing the database as a file on my machine. However, I also read about the possibility to set up a server. So when does it make sense to use a server and more specifically, would it make sense to use a server in my case?

Please see below my code for the creation of the database.

```
### SET UP
# set up database
db = sqlite3.connect("mydatabase.db")
cur = db.cursor()
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE t (sentence, ngram, word, probability);")
# set up variable to store db rows
to_db = []
# set input directory
indir = '~/data/'

### PARSE FILES
# loop through filenames in indir
for filename in os.listdir(indir):
    if filename.endswith(".txt"):
        filename = os.path.join(indir, filename)
        # open txt files in dir
        with io.open(filename, mode = 'r', encoding = 'utf-8') as mytxt:

            ### EXTRACT RELEVANT INFORMATION
            # for every line in txt file
            for i, line in enumerate(mytxt): 
                # strip linebreak
                line = line.strip()
                # read line where the sentence is stated
                if i == 0 or i % 9 == 0:
                    sentence = line
                    ngram = " ".join(line.split(" ")[:-1])
                    word = line.split(" ")[-1]
                # read line where the result is stated
                if (i-4) == 0 or (i-4) % 9 == 0:
                    result = line.split(r'=  ')[1].split(r' [')[0]
                    # make a tuple representing a new row of db
                    db_row = (sentence, ngram, word, result)
                    to_db.append(db_row)

            ### WRITE TO DATABASE               
            # add new row to db
            cur.executemany("INSERT INTO t (sentence, ngram, word, results) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?);", to_db)
            db.commit()
db.close()
```

Comment: It is not possible to achieve a significant speedup by writing one file to the database in parallel (e.g. 4cores - 1 file). However, you could process the files in parallel by using a tool like GNU parallel for easy multiprocessing, but you're limited by sqlite being single threaded. You're already grouping inserts into chunks, which hopefully helps your n+1 problem.

Comment: Maybe my explanation was unclear. I'd like to process x files on x cores in parallel and write the results to x databases. After that, I'd merge the databases into one database. I was wondering whether it is possible to let x processes write to one database immediately.

Comment: Okay so the merge scenario makes sense. x processes on x files meets the 1-to-1 core-to-database requirement that I suggested with GNU parallel, and your last question x processes/files per database would face the limitation i mentioned as sqlite is single threaded.

Answer (score 0):

> The whole process of creating the database could be significantly accelerated, if it is possible to write to a database in parallel

I am not sure of that. You only have little processing, so the whole process is likely to be io bound. SQLite is a very nice tool, but it only support one single thread to write into it.

Possible improvements:

- use x threads to read and process the text file, a single one to write to the database in large chunks and a queue. As the process is IO bound, the Python Global Interprocess Lock should not be a problem
- use a full featured database like PostgreSQL or MariaDB on a separate machine and multiple processes on the client machine  each processing its own set of input files

In either case, I am unsure of the benefit...

Answer (score 0):

I do daily updates to an SQLite database using python mutlithreading. It works beautifully. Two different tables have nearly 20,000,000 records one with 8 fields the other with 10. This is on my laptop which is 4 years old.

If you are having performance issues I recommend looking into how your tables are constructed (a proper primary key and indexes) and your equipment. If you are still using an HDD you will gain amazing performance by upgrading to an SSD.

Comment: I set the db up with ```cur.execute("CREATE TABLE t (sentence TEXT PRIMARY KEY, ngram TEXT, word TEXT, result FLOAT);")``` Rows look like ('this is an example', 'this is an', 'example', '577'). I read that it's not efficient to use a text as a primary key, but in my keys it seemed to be most convenient

Comment: If, in each record, the sentence == ngram & word, then you could drop the sentence column entirely and use a primary key of ngram and word. Don’t store repeated data if you don’t have to. You should also set an index on columns you query. Example if you query on WHERE word = ‘example’ create an index on word.

Comment: Each ngram and each word occur multiple times. However, each combination of ngram and word is unique. That's why I included sentence as primary key. I query always on ```WHERE ngram == 'a ngram' &  word == 'word'``` So should I set indices for ngram and word?

Comment: Also my PK in both tables are a combination of two fields: ticker TEXT, and Date DATE. Again, my DB is VERY performant.

Comment: Yes I understand and I was not questioning that. I'll make a combined PK. I was just wondering about the indices

Comment: If the combination of ngram and word is always unique I would set the PK to those two fields and delete the sentence column. UNLESS you need the complete sentence back in a query then it requires further thought. Does the word always come at the end of the sentence? Could the word be repeated in the same sentence? If either of these is ‘yes’ then you may have to keep the sentence column. Yes, I would create an index on ngram and word, specifying order based on the best logic for the way you query your table.

Comment: sentence is basically a combination of ngram and word. However, the word comes appears always in the end of the sentence and can be repeated twice in the sentence. For instance, a sentence like ```this is an an``` could be a possible sentence. But I guess that I still don't need the sentence column as I can always reconstruct it by combining ngram and word.

Comment: Just to make sure I’m not steering you wrong, you never have a sentence like “My dog sniffed another dog” with with ngram==‘My sniffed another’ and word ==‘dog’?

Comment: No, I don't. In every row the following holds: ```sentence = str(ngram + ' ' + word)```